# Blog into a table

Tags: blogs

I am currently revamping my own website, however, I have tried dotclear and chyrp, both are very good.
However, after many attempts trying to make the bog appear only in a table, I am giving up.

My aim is to have a blog inside of a table as shown in the image

http://i55.tinypic.com/2rfbtrn.jpg

Does anyone know how I can achieve that or know any other easier way or even another blog engine that allows me to do that?

Thank you.

Regads.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, I don’t have the technical details of your web application, but one way would be to place your blog inside an IFRAME (either instead of a table, or place the IFRAME inside the table).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do thing properly (not using an iframe), it is not possible at all. The reason is that a CMS generate a complete page, with a header and internal link.

My suggestion is to do it the other way: adapt the CMS to display a menu on the left and a title above.

In dotclear, this can be done easily by doing a template. Even better: your goal might be achievable by using some dotclear theme and some extensions like "simplemenu".